# Density principle in Quasi-Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I have an Operator $T: L^1(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow  w-L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where $w-L^1$ denotes the weak $L^1$ space endowed with the quasi-norm: $$ \|f\|_{w-L^1}=\sup_{\alpha>0} \ \alpha \cdot \lambda(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: \ |f(x)|\ge\alpha\}) $$ 
where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

If I know that **T is bounded on a dense subset** (set of all simple functions), why can't T be **extended to a bounded operator** on whole $L^1$?

As far as I know, the problem ist due to the relaxed triangle inequality in the Quasi-Banach space, i.e. $\|f+g\|_{w-L^1}\le C\cdot (\|f\|_{w-L^1}+\|g\|_{w-L^1})$. But I can't identify the problem in imitating the proof for Banach spaces as $w-L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is complete and boundedness of an operator is equivalent to continuity also in Quasi-Banach spaces.

EDIT: I found the post "[Is quasinorm always continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70762/is-quasinorm-always-continuous)" and probably the weak $L^1$ quasi-norm is not continuous and therefore the proof fails?